# Is there a difference between PhD student, doctoral student, doctorand and how to say "CIFRE"?

Tags: difference, translation

I was wondering if there was any difference between those three formulations:

- PhD student
- doctoral student
- doctorand

Plus, in France we have 2 types of doctorates:

- [Doctorat](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctorat) ([Doctorate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctorate))
- [CIFRE](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_industrielle_de_formation_par_la_recherche) (??)

I was wondering how to say "CIFRE" in an English document as I didn't find any English wikipedia page for that.

Comment: Related question, where I don't ask a translation or an English equivalent for CIFRE but if it exists something similar elsewhere https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/133145/is-there-an-equivalent-in-another-country-of-the-french-cifre

Comment: As far as I know _doctorand_ does not exist as an English word.

Comment: The answers likely varies from country to country (since education systems and classifications can vary), and is a matter of differences in Academia vs. language. There will be different understandings sometimes for the same terms in a US or UK sense even.

Comment: @ColinFine Is this wikipedia page wrong then? https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/doctorand

Comment: @JKHA: I did say "as far as I know". The OED does list it, and marks it as "frequency band 2", which are "almost exclusively terms which are not part of normal discourse and would be unknown to most people". The iWeb corpus has precisely one hit for "doctorand", which turns out to be an error for "doctor and", as do 51 out of the 52 hits on the "iWeb" corpus (the one which really is the word "doctorand", from peswiki.com, appears to have been written by a Norwegian). So yes, it is an Englsh word that appears in a couple of dictionaries. I have found no instance of its use by a native speaker.

Comment: @ColinFine Yes, no problem, I was wondering why Wikipedia didn’t mention it’s not spread ☺️ probably an edit to be done on this page :)